# How to view openshift online node application logs locally?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I can view my node application logs in the OpenShift Online interface at:

```
OpenShift > Applications > Deployments > [ pod_name ] > [ deployment_name ] > Logs
```

[image]

How can I view them locally?

Comment: For a lot of detail on using the command line, including viewing logs, you may want to read the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to get a list of your pods, run:

```
oc get pods
```

It will return something like:

```
NAME                      READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-24-rtls           1/1       Running     0          45d
showcase-node-501-build   0/1       Completed   0          21h
showcase-node-502-build   0/1       Completed   0          21h
showcase-node-530-wcwzm   1/1       Running     1          21h
```

To view the log screen for the node app, run:

```
oc logs showcase-node-530-wcwzm -f
```